# Under Windows 7 and 8, openfiles.exe cannot be launched by another application

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, c++builder

If I use C++ Windows API "CreateProcess" or C run-time library "system" to launch most processes, they run fine. But if I use the same to launch openfiles.exe as in "openfiles.exe /query" under Windows 7 and 8 it never works. It complains about needing a 32-bit OS to be running, or, if I elevate it with runas, I get Invalid Function. There is definitely something peculiar about openfiles.exe under Win 7 and 8, and, despite it working fine from a command prompt, it never runs when launched by another process. Why?

Comment: I suspect this is a problem with 32bit vs 64bit executables.  IIRC, even on 64bit systems, openfiles.exe is a 32bit exe.  Look at the CreateProcess flags and make sure you're doing the right thing for the 32/64bit context.

Comment: It is the kind of error you get when you try to run a 16-bit program on a 64-bit operating system.  Look for a file named "openfiles.com" on your machine.

Comment: The problem is still there under Win 7 32-bit. The error message is a red herring.

Comment: It appears that Microsoft have restricted the launching of openfiles.exe from other apps as of Win 7 onwards. From a command prompt it all works OK, but anything else is a "no go". It seems like it is looking at the process chain when launched and not running if the chain is not what is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems under Windows 64 bit, the application must be also 64 bit one (not sure for 32 bit OS).

My system is Windows 7 64 bit and if I build my app with "Target Platform" set to "64-bit Windows", the following works.

```
::ShellExecuteW( this->Handle, NULL, L"openfiles.exe", L"/query", NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL );
```

I believe other launching options also would work like CreateProcess.

But gives the same error you when built as 32-bit application.